Meta conversions API (How to refresh long term token)
Meta is giving long term token (usually which lasts 60 days) to refresh this we need to use short term token (which lasts 2-3 hours before expiration, after that we cant use it second time to generate long term token) which means after 60 day i have to manually access my dashboard to retrieve short-term token and put it in my script to generate long token again.
Is there any way I can access and generate short term token with API?
There is nothing in documentation regarding to this, as meta provides i have to go through login flow again to generate new token (which also if possible to do this with api ?)
